# getting a 'File' is an ambiguous reference error while insert file in google drive account

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I am getting an error while insert file in google drive account using the below code

> 'File' is an ambiguous reference between 'Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File' and 'System.IO.File'

```
 private static File insertFile(DriveService service, String title, String description, String parentId, String mimeType, String filename)
        {
            // File's metadata.
            File body = new File();
            body.Title = title;
            body.Description = description;
            body.MimeType = mimeType;

            // Set the parent folder.
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(parentId))
            {
                body.Parents = new List<ParentReference>() { new ParentReference() { Id = parentId } };
            }

            // File's content.
            byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

            try
            {
                FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, mimeType);
                request.Upload();

                File file = request.ResponseBody;

                // Uncomment the following line to print the File ID.
                // Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + file.Id);

                return file;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Both namespaces (`Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data` and `System.IO`) defines `class` `File` and, probably, you have both namespaces "included" with `using` statment.

You need to choose which one you need and use it with fully qualified name (e.g. `System.IO.File` or `Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File` depends on your needs).

If you wish to reduce keystrokes while writing code, you can do:

```
using GoogleDataAPI = Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data;
```

And then use `GoogleDataAPI` instead of `Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i have added name space Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data but adding File after the Data is not working does i have to add any dll.

Answer (score 2):

**`Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data`** and **`System.IO`** both define **File** class, so use full name 
**`Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File`** and **`System.IO.File`**

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is then qualify the File type, if it will always been on a google drive, then set it to 'Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File'

Answer (score 0):

I have a lot of class names that are identical, yet reside in different namespaces.

The other answers are correct; you can get around this by fully qualifying the class with its namespace.  I prefer to use a using alias.

```
using System.IO;
using google = Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data;
```

Any reference to System.IO.File can be left unqualified.  Any time you need to reference Google's file class, you can simply use (for example):-

```
var googleFile = new google.File();
```

Answer (score 0):

don't give only File in definition ,go for the full namespace while defining